# A short summary of what BCNF is?

Tags: bcnf

For my exam I am revising for in January I will need to know all about Boyce-Codd Normal Form and possibly have to write a short summary about what it is. 
In a paragraph or so, what exactly is BCNF as I have looked on many sites and the descriptions are quite complex so it's not easy to get my head around. Thank you for any help.

Comment: @james..look at my answer..

Comment: @James..the pdf in the below link gives you the practical example of what bcnf is..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Boyce–Codd Normal Form (BCNF)**
A relation R(X) is in Boyce–Codd Normal
Form if for every non-trivial functional
dependency Y → Z defined on it, Y contains
a key K of R(X).

That is, Y is a superkey for
R(X).

Example: Person1(SI#, Name, Address)

```
     The only FD is SI# → Name, Address
```

Since SI# is a key, Person1 is in BCNF

Anomalies and redundancies, as discussed
earlier, do not occur in databases with
relations in BCNF.

**Non-BCNF examples:**

Person(SI#,Name,Address,Hobby)

The FD `SI# → Name`,Address does not satisfy
conditions for BCNF since the key is
{SSN,Hobby}

```
HasAccount(AcctNum,ClientId,OfficeId)

The FD AcctNum → OfficeId does not satisfy
BCNF conditions if we assume that keys for
HasAccount are {ClientId,OfficeId} and
{AcctNum,ClientId}, rather than AcctNum.
```

You can refer to below link for detailed explanation.
[http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc343h/fall/08/lectures/wk12/wk12_BCNF2-up.pdf](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/%7Ecsc343h/fall/08/lectures/wk12/wk12_BCNF2-up.pdf)

Hope it helps..